# Tomcat restart, no all apps start

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat5.5

I've an interesting problem about start/restart of tomcat 5.5

I've deployed n webapps on my tomcat. All webapps work correctly.

Every time when I restart tomcat, never happen that all webapps starts.

If I "click" manually over tomcat manager start link of that webapp no started, that webapp start.

Can anyone suggest me any solution or idea for resolve this problem?

Thanks so much!

Tommy

Comment: good idea, i've post this question so there :-)

Comment: Any useful logging available?

Comment: Usually I would guess there is a problem with the way the application is written, but I think you should provide more details:
 - Always the same web applications that do not start?
 - How large is 'n', still <10?
 - Can you observe the same behavior with Tomcat 6?

Comment: how many applications do you have in the webapps folder? Are some of them in a virtual host? I assume from your question that every time you start tomcat a different app doesn't start, but is that right?

Comment: same problem, log files revealed the cause, it was the fact that more than one app had no webapprootkey, and tomcat was assigning a default "webapp.root" to both, but the second time, it failed, because that key had already been assigned. anyways, looking at the log files is probably a good place to start-

Answer (score 1):

I have had issues with restarting tomcat in that the server does not finish stopping tomcat before it starts it again. Sometimes this results in port conflicts, but more commonly just bizarre behavior. I now make it standard practice to stop tomcat, verify no running tomcat/java processes (unix: ps, windows: taskmgr) and then start tomcat back up.

Answer (score 0):

See if this is of any help :

[Tomcat Web Application Manager How To](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/html-manager-howto.html)

(Though it is for version 4.4, you can search more on that website)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at this question for a potential answer, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470609/why-is-a-tomcat-webapp-failing-when-an-almost-identical-app-starts-within-the-sam), it may help.