# Why is a Tomcat webapp failing when an almost identical app starts within the same Tomcat instance?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat5.5, tomcat

We're experiencing slightly strange webapp deployment behaviour under Tomcat 5.5.27 on Linux (both on CentOS in production and Ubuntu 10.04 for development).

App A and app B are almost identical (exactly the same libraries, a copied Maven project), App B differs only in that its JPA entities are annotated to access a different table within the same schema (the JNDI database references are identical).

When the apps are deployed into either environment, app B will ***not*** start. However:

1. Manually starting the stalled app, from the Tomcat admin console, works fine (???).
2. After any attempt to restart Tomcat, the alphabetically later app fails to start. Point #1 still remains valid (???)
3. Logging *is* configured (log4j), however, we get nothing from [the yet-to-start] app B's logging, nor errors from Tomcat's 'catalina.out' log file (NB. logging ***is*** working once the apps are up and running).

I've done a reasonably thorough search for information (Apache/Tomcat bugzilla, Google) but I've found nothing of real use. Other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737983/tomcat-6-whats-the-significance-of-antiresourcelocking-antijarlocking) have sighted the use of the antijarlocking and antiresourcelocking attributes on the server's 'context.xml' 'Context' node, but there is also a suggestion that this is unecessary/inaffective under Linux (hasn't appeared to work here, either).

Any ideas?

Cheers

Rich

P.S. Upgrading from Tomcat 5.5.x isn't an option, currently (IT support etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a similar behavior to spring applications on tomcat. -- They require that the webAppRootKey is unique for each application. -- If not the applications behave like you described, so in case of Spring apps, make sure that App-A has an other webAppRootKey then App-B.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>myRootKey</param-value>
</context-param>
```

@See http://groups.google.com/group/riotfamily/browse_thread/thread/9a0edf69575d3ab6?pli=1

Comment: Ralph, I'll have a look into this and let you know how I get on. It's notable that you mention Spring as, yes, these are a Spring-based applications ;-) . Also, thanks for the speedy reply.

Comment: does what it says on the tin! Yep, that works. Strangely, I have a vague recolection that we have set this webAppRootKey on another project, sometime in the last 4-5 years (really ;-) ). Thanks again.